# Can someone explain the Kronecker Product?

Tags: matrices

I am in the final two weeks before the Calculus 2 exam and we just started with the topic 'vector differentiation'.

We use a reader which is written by a PHD student but it is everything expect clear. I hope someone can help me explain the Kronecker product in a basic way.

Comment: Please don't yell in the title...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html